# equilibrium point of an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If a trajectory of the ODE $x'(t) = f(x(t))$ reaches the equilibrium of it  then is it true that it stays there forever ? Why ? I think I am missing something trivial (Hint enough).

Comment: If $f(x)$ is differentiable at the fixed point, the trajectory will takes forever to reach the fixed point instead of reaches the fixed point at finite time and stay there forever. The simplest example is the ODE $x' = -x$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it depends, it will stay forever only if the equilibrium point is stable, you should look at the Lyapunov stability.